# Minimal polynomial versus Algebraic multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $K$ be a field, $A$ be a square matrix with coefficients in $K$ and $\lambda\in K$. Usually, people call the **algebraic multiplicity** of $\lambda$ to the the biggest integer $a\ge 0$ such that 
$(X-\lambda)^a$ divides the characteristic polynomial.

Is there a name of the biggest integer $m\ge 0$ such that $(X-\lambda)^m$ divides the ***minimal polynomial*** of $A$ ?

This number seems to be indeed interesting.

Remark: People usually call **geometric multiplicity** the dimension of the eigenspace associated to $\lambda$. Writing this $g$, we find 
$$g\le a, m\le a$$
but we cannot really compare $g$ with $m$: both inequalities $g\le m$ or $m\le g$ are possible. Looking at the Jordan form (by extending the scalars if needed), then $a$ is the sum of the sizes of blocks with eigenvalues $\lambda$, $g$ is the number of blocks and $m$ is the size of the biggest block.

Comment: I don't know of any relation but the following: the matrix is diagonalisable if and only if $m=1$ for each of its eigenvalues.

Comment: True, this is another evidence why $m$ is interesting. Even if one also could argue that $m=1$ if and only if $g=a$.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks, this seems to be indeed what I was looking for. I never heard about this quantity before. By the way, the link you indicate does not seem to work

Comment: It is the size of the largest Jordan block associated to λ, and is called the index of λ, see [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Uniqueness). Fixed the link.